# Вставлять элементы 1 массива между элементами 2 массива в шахматном порядке!

Tags: c++, c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть 2 массива нужно вставлять элементы из 1 массива во второй в шахматном порядке пока не закончатся элементы 1 массива, когда они закончатся просто оставить цифры 2 массива в покое.

```
int n;
int mas1[101];
int mas2[101];

cout << "Number of actionis: ";
cin >> n;

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    mas1[i] = i;
}

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    mas2[i] = 0;
}

int *masbuff2 = new int[n];
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    masbuff2[i] = i;

int *masbuff1 = new int[100 - n];
for (int i = 1, k = (100 - n); i <= k; i++)
    masbuff1[i] = i;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    masbuff2[i] = mas1[i];
}

for(int i = n; i <= 100; i++){
    masbuff1[i - n] = mas1[i];
}
```

в mas2 собирался записывать элементы.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: C++ тут упомянут только потому что `new` вместо `malloc()` и `cout/cin` вместо `printf()/scanf()`? Или действительно интересует решение задачи на C++?

Comment: действительно интересует решение задачи на C++

Comment: могу предоставить то как я пытался решить, но у меня не получилось

Comment: for(int i  = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  if(i < n){
   if((i % 2) == 0){
    mas2[i] = masbuff2[i];  
   }
   else if((i % 2) != 0){
    mas2[i] = masbuff1[i];
   }
  }
  else if(i > n){
   mas2[i] = masbuff1[i];  
  }
 }

Comment: Кстати, вы постоянно вылезаете за пределы массива (индексация начинается не с 1, а с 0).

Comment: я начинаю индексацию с 1 но <= 100, то есть тоже самое количество места(удобно если у вас числа в массиве от 1 до 100). Если я конечно правильно понял замечание

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите получить. Допустим, есть массив `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` и массив `21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30`. Что вы хотите получить в результате? Что значит вводимое значение `n`?

Comment: Элемент с индексом `100` - *сто первый* по счёту, а у вас всего 100 элементов в массиве.

Comment: результат примерно должен быть таким: мас1 = 1 2 3(при n = 3), мас2(3 4 5 ... 100)   результат массив в котором (3 1 4 2 5 3 6 7 8 ...100)

Comment: Все, сдаюсь. Когда нет ТЗ, результат - ХЗ. Если внятно сумеете изложить задание - пишите, а при таком изложении совершенно непонятно, что ты хотите получить. По-моему, вы сами никак для себя не поймете, что вам нужно, и потому и не понимаете, как это получить. Как поймете, что же вы на самом деле хотите - так сразу все получится :) У вас массив не может оставться тем же по размеру, как минимум - при таком изложении.

Comment: я понимаю что я хочу получить я не понимаю как это сделать из-за скудных знаний в с/с++. Возможно не понятно объяснил, но тут уж как получилось. Мне просто нужно записывать числа из 2 массивов в 3 через 1 число ( шахматный порядок), то есть число из 2 массива число из 1 массива число из 2 число из 1. и так пока не закончатся числа в 1 массиве, когда они закончатся(ели законится) проложить заполнять числами со 2 массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/en9eFk

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const size_t n = 3;

    int a[n] = {1, 3, 5};
    int b[n] = {2, 4, 6};

    int c[n<<1];

    for (size_t q=0, i=0; q<n; ++q)
        c[i++] = a[q], c[i++] = b[q];

    for (int x : c)
        printf("%d ", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помог ваш ответ